# Angular Onclick() not working on second button

Tags: javascript, angular, html

As you can see in the code, there are two onClick() methods. Both appear on the UI. But when I click on the second onClick() method, it doesn't call the method but the first one calls. I am not able to understand why this is happening. Please help.

```
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right mrg-top-15">
            <div class="action-btns text-right flex">
                <span class="icon-pending"></span>
                <vh-button [type]="'trash'" (onClick)="navigateToHRA()" class="mrg-lft-10" id="icd-delete"></vh-button>
            </div>
            <button (onClick)="navigateToHRA()" class="btn btn-primary">{{'LookUpButtonText'|translate}}</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `(click)` when using Angular's click event.

```
<button (click)="navigateToHRA()" class="btn btn-primary">{{'LookUpButtonText'|translate}}</button>
```

The other `(onClick)` event is most probably the output event emitter of `vh-button` component/directive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `(click)` on the button instead of `(onClick)` because that event does not exist on the native button.